# Can I select a list of Blob with CQL?

Tags: cql, scylla

I store all `event_id` in blob type and would like to select multiple `event_id` at once.

It works well if I send the query one by one. Like this one:

```
SELECT JSON event_id, user FROM demo.events WHERE customer_id=1234 AND event_id=0x123123;
```

But I would like to use `IN` clause to query multiple `event_id` at the same time. I've tried the following CQL but failed:

```
SELECT JSON event_id, user FROM demo.events WHERE customer_id=1234 AND event_id in [0x123123, 0x456456, 0x789789];
```

An error message is given

```
SyntaxException: line 1:106 no viable alternative at input 'event_id'
```

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IN` operator [requires](https://docs.scylladb.com/getting-started/dml/) `tuble_literal` on the right side of the expression. [Tuples](https://docs.scylladb.com/getting-started/types/#grammar-token-tuple-literal) can be defined with `()`. In your case `IN (x, y, z)` would work:

```
$ create table test.a (customer_id int, event_id blob, user text, PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, event_id));

$ insert into test.a (customer_id, event_id, user) values (1, 0x123123, 'a');
$ insert into test.a (customer_id, event_id, user) values (1, 0x123124, 'a');
$ insert into test.a (customer_id, event_id, user) values (1, 0x123125, 'a');

$ SELECT JSON event_id, user FROM test.a WHERE customer_id=1 AND event_id in (0x123123, 0x123124);

[json]
---------------------------------------
 {"event_id": "0x123123", "user": "a"}
 {"event_id": "0x123124", "user": "b"}

(2 rows)
```